# how to save bash command exit code AND also the pid of this command?

Tags: linux, bash

```
  salt   -L servers state.apply  tomcat.fullstart concurrent=True 
  deploy_pid=$!
  exit_code=$?
  [ $exit_code -ne 0 ] && echo "An error occured during applying tomcat salt state" && exit $exit_code

  wait $deploy_pid
```

I want to get the exit code of the first salt command, the above I think the exit code is from deploy_pid=$! , not from the first salt command.
I also need the salt command pid so wait on it.

How can I do this? thanks

Comment: When you run something in the foreground, the command after it doesn't start until after it exited and its PID has been freed for reuse; thus, it doesn't update `$!` because that PID so no longer valid and has been freed for other applications to use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem it describes does not actually exist: by the time a command run in the foreground is complete, there _is_ no PID to be stored.

Answer (score 4):

You're not running `salt` in the background, so `deploy_pid=$!` isn't meaningful.

If you were running it in the background, you can't check its exit status before you `wait` because it has to actually exit first. So the order of operations needs to be:

1. Run `salt` in the background by using `&`
2. Store its PID
3. At some point in the future, `wait` for it
4. Get the exit status of `wait`

```
#                                                         Put salt in background
#                                                                |
#                                                                V
 salt   -L servers state.apply  tomcat.fullstart concurrent=True &
  deploy_pid=$! # get the PID of the backgrounded process
  wait "$deploy_pid" # wait for salt to finish
  exit_code=$? # get the exit status
```

Also, as a closing thought, if you are going to background a process and then immediately wait for it then maybe you don't need to background it at all unless you *really* need to know what PID it ran with for some reason.

Something like this is more straightforward if you don't need backgrounding:

```
if salt -L servers state.apply  tomcat.fullstart concurrent=True ; then
  echo "Salt worked. Do success stuff here."
else
  echo "Salt failed. Do failure stuff here."
fi
```